# Pyramid equivalent to Django's syncdb command?

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, web-frameworks, pyramid

I noticed in the [Pyramid + SQLAlchemy + URL Dispatch Wiki Tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/tutorials/wiki2/index.html) that the database is initialized in the main function when the application is run.

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    """ This function returns a WSGI application.
    """
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    initialize_sql(engine)
    # -- and so on ---
```

where `initialize_sql` is defined as follows:

```
def initialize_sql(engine):
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    try:
        session = DBSession()
        page = Page('FrontPage', 'initial data')
        session.add(page)
        transaction.commit()
    except IntegrityError:
        # already created
        pass
```

which essentially creates all of the tables (if they don't exist) and populates it with some initial values.   Easy enough to understand, BUT...

This is just a tutorial to demonstrate a small application, so how it is typically done in production may differ (or not...).  This brings me to my question:

When using Pyramid with SQLAlchemy, is it a typical pattern in production for a database to be initialized this way, or is it typical to use something equivalent to a `manage syncdb` command in Django that is invoked manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since Pyramid does not make any assumptions about data models, it does not attempt to manage them for you. This is entirely up to you and what specific data layer you are using.

With respect to using SQLAlchemy, it is possible to manage migrations using the SQLAlchemy-migrate package. When you set this up, it provides you with a `manage` command to perform migrations.

Comment: To clarify:

I am most likely planning on using SQLAlchemy (which I am new to as well).

While I do find appealing the philosophy of Pyramid's design, I have not found any good examples of how it is typically used.

Is the tutorial example above a legitimate, common way of doing db initialization?  Or should this just be treated as a toy "Hello World" site?

(I am trying to do what I can to avoid the prospect of reinventing a square-wheel syncdb command myself).

Comment: This is not how it is done in production sites, but is convenient for tutorials. Migrations are something that is always variable. Django has South, SQLAlchemy has SQLAlchemy-migrate, and you can always just use raw SQL migration scripts as well. Initializing and migrating a database are almost always different from project to project or company to company.